# Jerkson makes Scala JSON so easy, can it be the same for XML?

Tags: xml, scala, playframework

Admittedly I really love the Jerkson library because it makes generating JSON so easy. Take for example:

```
Json(generate(Job.search(parseDate(date),accountId)
      .map(job => Map("id" -> job.id,
      "name" -> job.name,
      "userId" -> job.userId.getOrElse("")
    ))))
```

But I am having difficulty finding a similar library that could generate and serialize XML nodes, etc., as easily as this. Is there a Java or Scala lib that could generate the nodes and values in a simple syntax without having to make "templates" or manually write the nodes?

Comment: Suppose that such library do exist, what would be the resulting XML given the `Map` you showed in your example ?

Comment: at first thought it might look just like an rss feed. `<xml xmlns:a10="blah"><job><id>1</id><name>DeLonge</name></job><job>...</job></xml>` in this case i'm not worried about attributes, it's more for a fast track to build an API that outputs the same data as a JSON API

Comment: I've been playing around with Lift's Scala JSON lib...this looks promising, although it might be more of a hack than a clean serialization...I'll post an answer if it turns out to be a clean method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much more difficult to build XML than JSON, because of the "double hierarchy" of attributes and children nodes. JSON structure is easily represented with standard Scala collections, by nesting maps and lists.

But if your are just interested in a subset of XML, the problems is less complex. According to your answer to my comment, the following snippet could be enough for what you need:

```
def tag( name: String, content: Seq[Node] ): Node =
  <xml></xml>.copy( label = name, child = content )

def toXML( label: String, content: String ): Node =
  tag( label, Text( content ) ) 

def toXML( root: String, map: Map[_,_] ): Node = {
  val children = for( (k,v) <- map ) yield {
    v match {
      case m: Map[_,_] => toXML( k.toString, m )
      case a => toXML(k.toString, a.toString )
    }
  }
  tag( root, children.toSeq )
}
```

It works as expected. For instance:

```
 val data = Map(
  "id" -> 121,
  "foo" -> Map(
    "hoo" -> "bar",
    "goo" -> "baz"
  )
)

val xml = convert.toXML( "example", data )
```

Then `xml` will be equal to:

```
<example>
  <id>121</id>
  <foo>
    <hoo>bar</hoo>
    <goo>baz</goo>
  </foo>
</example>
```

It's just a quick and dirty hack, but I think it can be easily improved (to include lists for instance) and made safer.

Comment: It almosts looks like the start of your own library ;) I might have to make some adjustments (like you said...Lists) but its got potential. I'll follow up if I've got any useful improvements, just too bad a lib doesn't already exist like this. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that XML is a native type in Scala? You can just return the XML straight away, no library needed.

See [this](http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.com/2009/11/xml-generation-with-scala.html) for examples.

Comment: wait a sec...is it really that dead simple? so if i insert the map in the example above into an XML node it will just serialize it all as XML? Am I missing something here?

Comment: yes, it should be quite straightforward. I'm not sure which exact output you want, so the implementation may differ slightly but, as you can see, you can just output xml, so...

Comment: i'll test this, the biggest concern i see is the issue where scala puts out html entities...not sure how it would treat a controller object's map but we shall see...

Comment: I don't think the map will be serialized to XML... It will rather be converted to a string and included as XML text.

Comment: @paradigmatic well, without a sample is hard, but as per this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215767/scala-how-to-create-xml-nodes-from-some-collection it should work, somehow

Comment: I gave it a solid attempt but this approach might require more maintenance than it looks. If I take the map above, the Tuple seems to confuse Scala and instead it outputs it as `(node, val)` instead of `<node>val</node>`. I'll keep experimenting to see if I can make it work.

Comment: It doesn't confuse Scala, it's just converted to its String representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML inline in Scala:

```
val someNode = <root>
                   <child>
                       Some stuff goes here
                   </child>
               </root>

someNode \ "child" // returns the child node

someNode \ "child" text // returns the text of the child node
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a library which does this (just not via Scala Xml) - Scales Xml provides exactly that kind of building DSL:

```
val ns = Namespace("test:uri")
val nsa = Namespace("test:uri:attribs")
val nsp = nsa.prefixed("pre")

val builder = 
  ns("Elem") /@ (nsa("pre", "attr1") -> "val1",
               "attr2" -> "val2",
       nsp("attr3") -> "val3") /(
    ns("Child"),
    "Mixed Content",
    ns("Child2") /( ns("Subchild") ~> "text" )
  )
```

See [here for more detailed documentation](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.1/0.3-RC5/XmlDsl.html)